# What is an example of function f:Z→N that is a bijection?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I tried to look at the cases and find a function, but I could not find a bijective function. I know that we should check the cases when x is a positive number and when x is negative. Can you help me to find one?

Comment: An idea: map the positive integers to twice their value. Any idea how to map the non-positive integers...?

Comment: map them to -x, so they will become positive. But still this function is not bijective

Comment: Don't map them to just $-x$, map them to the odd integers.

Comment: Have you heard the story of the Hilbert's Grand Hotel?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel What does the desk man do if the hotel is full and a bus load with an infinite number of tourists arrive?

Comment: @BellePepper Nop. You've already covered the even naturals, so what is there left? The odd ones...so how can you map the negative integers (and zero) **onto** them?

Comment: @DonAntonio can I map neagtive integers to -(x+1)/2?

Comment: @BellePepper That's close...but not quite: what about $\;x=-4\;$ , for example? That'd go to $\;-\frac{-4+1}2=\frac32\notin\Bbb N\;$ ... yet you're really close...

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:
$$f(n) = \begin{cases}
2n, \quad n\geq0 \\
-2n-1, \quad n <0 \\
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
\mathbb Z: & 0 & & & 1 & -1 & & & 2 & -2 & & & 3 & -3 & & & 4 & -4 & & & 5 & -5 & & & \cdots \\
& \updownarrow & & & \updownarrow & \updownarrow & & & \updownarrow & \updownarrow & & & \updownarrow & \updownarrow & & & \updownarrow & \updownarrow & & & \updownarrow & \updownarrow & & & \cdots \\
\mathbb N: & 0 & & & 1 & 2 & & & 3 & 4 & & & 5 & 6 & & & 7 & 8 & & & 9 & 10 & & & \cdots
\end{array}
$$